# Query LinkedIn Specific Company Details

Tags: json, linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve company details from it's ID. I got a list of company ids and asked to get company details like Name, Address.... in json format.

I check the LinkedIn API but it looks like that it allows you to query your own company only.

Following allows me to query list of company details.

http://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=See&types=company

is it possible to query a specific company details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Yes!
LinkedIn has REST API available to fetch and update details on LinkedIn. 
The service https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337?format=json can be used to fetch details of the company whose id is 1337.</s>

For full REST API docs refer to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337?format=json.

But there are quite a few restrictions on getting these details. Read through the REST API documentation for full details.
Hope this helps!

As of May 2015, the API has changed and there is no way to fetch company details from LinkedIn REST API unless you are the administrator of the page.

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Comment: I tried this already. It only allows us to read own company details, not others

Comment: This is by design, as of the May 2015 changes referenced above.